# Algorithm for Constructing a Projection Matrix onto the Null Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, projection, projection-matrices

I am using MATLAB to write functions that generate projection matrices onto the column space, **col($A$)**, and null space, **null($A$)**, of an input matrix $A$.

I have the column space projection working but when I apply a slightly altered algorithm to write the function generating the null space projection matrix, my null space projector results do not fulfill the general conditions for a projection matrix, as I understand them.

Here is how I algorithmically proceed for (successfully) generating projection matrices onto **col(A)**:

1. Take input $A$ which is an ($m\times n)$ matrix.
2. Run **B = span_basis(A)**. This function creates a matrix B whose columns are basis vectors spanning **col(A)**.
3. Run **[Q,~] = qr(B)**. This grabs matrix Q from B's QR-factorization.
4. Re-define Q to **Q = Q(all rows, columns 1 thru rank(A))**. This makes sure that Q's columns are now only the vectors constituting the ortho-normal basis of **col(A)**.
5. I then use nested for-loops to generate the entries of the projection matrix $P$ onto **col(A)**. The loops run on indices $i$ and $j$ from 1 to size(Q). Each entry $P(i,j)$ is the dot product between rows of $Q$:

   $P(i,j) = Q(i,:) \cdot Q(j,:)$

Once I've done these things, I have a projection matrix $P$ onto the column space of $A$. I then test

(i) $P = P^T$

(ii) $P^2=P$

(iii) rank(A) = rank(P)

(iv) $PA = A$

Those all work out. Thus, $P$ is a projection matrix.

***However***, problems arise when I repeat these same steps - slightly altered - to get the projection onto **null(A)**:

1. Take input $A$ which is an ($m\times n)$ matrix. Make $A^T$ which is $(n \times m)$.
2. Run **B = span_basis($A^T$)**. This creates a matrix B whose columns are basis vectors spanning **col($A^T$)**.
3. Run **[Q,~] = qr(B)**. This grabs matrix Q from B's QR-factorization.
4. Re-define Q to **Q = Q(all rows, columns 1 thru rank($A^T$))**. This makes sure that Q's columns are the vectors constituting the ortho-normal basis of **col($A^T$)**.
5. I then use nested for-loops to generate the entries of the projection matrix $P$ onto col($A^T$). The loops run on indices $i$ and $j$ from 1 to size(Q). Each $P(i,j)$ is the dot product between rows of $Q$:

   $P(i,j) = Q(i,:) \cdot Q(j,:)$
6. I then finally get the projection onto null(A) as $\tilde{P} = \mathbb{I} -P $.

I then check rank($A^T$) = rank($\tilde{P}$), $\tilde{P}^2=\tilde{P}$ and $\tilde{P}^T = \tilde{P}$.

However, it is my understanding that, in addition to these conditions, I should be getting $\tilde{P}A^T=A^T$. However, this is not the case. Instead, when I grab the absolute value of the maximum difference between entries of $\tilde{P}A^T$ and $A^T$, I always get something around 1 (usually 0.99...), i.e.,

max(abs($\tilde{P}A^T-A^T$), [], "all") = 0.99...

That means that $\tilde{P}A^T$ and $A^T$ are not equal, as - at least to my understanding - they should be.

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine. Steps 1-4 is equivalent to running Gram-Schmidt on the columns of $A$, weeding out the linearly dependent vectors. The resulting matrix $Q$ has columns that form an orthonormal basis whose span is the same as $A$. Thus, projecting onto $\operatorname{colspace} Q$ is equivalent to projecting onto $\operatorname{colspace} A$. Step 5 simply computes $QQ^\top$, which is the projection matrix $Q(Q^\top Q)^{-1}Q^\top$, since the columns of $Q$ are orthonormal, and hence $Q^\top Q = I$.

When you modify your algorithm, you are simply performing the same steps on $A^\top$. The resulting matrix $P$ will be the projector onto $\operatorname{col} (A^\top) = (\operatorname{null} A)^\perp$. To get the projector onto the orthogonal complement $\operatorname{null} A$, you take $\tilde{P} = I - P$.

As such, $\tilde{P}^2 = \tilde{P} = \tilde{P}^\top$, as with all orthogonal projections. I'm not sure how you got $\operatorname{rank} \tilde{P} = \operatorname{rank} A$; you should be getting
$$\operatorname{rank} \tilde{P} = \dim \operatorname{null} A = n - \operatorname{rank} A.$$
Perhaps you computed $\operatorname{rank} P$ instead?

Correspondingly, we would also expect $P$, the projector onto $\operatorname{col}(A^\top)$, to satisfy $PA^\top = A^\top$, but not for $\tilde{P}$. In fact, we would expect $\tilde{P}A^\top = 0$; all the columns of $A^\top$ are orthogonal to $\operatorname{null} A$, so projecting each of them should produce $0$. Or, more directly,
$$PA^\top = A^\top \implies IA^\top - PA^\top = 0 \implies (I - P)A^\top = 0 \implies \tilde{P}A^\top = 0.$$
I would double check these things: check that $\tilde{P} A^\top$ is indeed $0$, and that $\operatorname{rank} \tilde{P} = n - \operatorname{rank} A$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see that I was incorrect to check rank($\tilde{P}$) = rank($A^T$). When constructing $\tilde{P}$, I should be checking rank($\tilde{P}$) = $n$ - rank($A$). I am then also constructing matrix $Q$ incorrectly in the case of the null space projector, right? Because I have it as Q = Q(all rows, columns 1 thru rank($A^T$)). But shouldn't it then be Q = Q(all rows, columns 1 thru $n$ - rank($A$)), i.e. Q = Q(all rows, 1 thru nullity(A))?

Comment: @AD203 I wouldn't over-think it. $Q$ is just one step along the way to constructing $P$, the projector onto $\operatorname{col}(A^\top)$ (or the colspace of whatever matrix you're dealing with). Since $\operatorname{col}(A^\top)$ is the perpendicular complement of what you really want to be projecting onto, you take $I - P$. Once you have $P$, you don't need $Q$ for anything else. Just follow the same steps to find $P$, and make the final modification at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I see now. Yes, I was overthinking. Since in the second algorithm, $P$ is the projector onto col($A^T$), it is actually correct to have the columns of Q run as those from 1 thru rank($A^T$) because at that point in the algorithm, we are still doing what we were doing in first algorithm. Again, thanks very much for helping out.

Comment: @AD203 No problem!